Error process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\yolov11.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000139, STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND) in OpenCV
I was trying to run simple YoloV11 in Rust. But I keep getting this following error :
error: process didn't exit successfully: target\debug\yolov11.exe (exit code: 0xc0000139, STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND)
No other errors are displayed. I already have Clang and OpenCV 4 installed in my Windows. When I ran a tool named dependency walker (https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to track which dependency might be missing, I got result missing these files, reached text length limit so I host the files name list in this url : https://traff.co/PAODef0q
It seems the error is related to the OpenCV binding. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this error and how to fix it?
Here are the code for more information :
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "yolov11"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ort = { version = "2.0.0-rc.8", features = ["load-dynamic"]}
ndarray = "0.16"
image = "0.25"
opencv = { version = "0.93.3", features = ["clang-runtime"] }

Main.rs
use opencv::{
    prelude::*,
    videoio,
    core,
    highgui,
    imgproc,
};
use image::{ImageBuffer, Rgb};
use ndarray::{Array, Axis, s};
use ort::{CPUExecutionProvider, Session, SessionOutputs, inputs};
use image::imageops::FilterType;
use image::GenericImageView;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct BoundingBox {
    x1: f32,
    y1: f32,
    x2: f32,
    y2: f32
}

fn intersection(box1: &BoundingBox, box2: &BoundingBox) -> f32 {
    (box1.x2.min(box2.x2) - box1.x1.max(box2.x1)) * (box1.y2.min(box2.y2) - box1.y1.max(box2.y1))
}

fn union(box1: &BoundingBox, box2: &BoundingBox) -> f32 {
    ((box1.x2 - box1.x1) * (box1.y2 - box1.y1)) + ((box2.x2 - box2.x1) * (box2.y2 - box2.y1)) - intersection(box1, box2)
}

#[rustfmt::skip]
const YOLOV8_CLASS_LABELS: [&str; 80] = [
    "person", "bicycle", "car", "motorcycle", "airplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat", "traffic light",
    "fire hydrant", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant",
    "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack", "umbrella", "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis", "snowboard",
    "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat", "baseball glove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle",
    "wine glass", "cup", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli",
    "carrot", "hot dog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "couch", "potted plant", "bed", "dining table", "toilet",
    "tv", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard", "cell phone", "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator",
    "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors", "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush"
];

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    ort::init()
        .with_execution_providers([CPUExecutionProvider::default().build()])
        .commit()?;

    let model = Session::builder()?.commit_from_file("./yolo11n.onnx")?;
    let mut cap = videoio::VideoCapture::from_file("./video.mp4", videoio::CAP_ANY)?;
    
    let frame_width = cap.get(videoio::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)? as i32;
    let frame_height = cap.get(videoio::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)? as i32;
    let fps = cap.get(videoio::CAP_PROP_FPS)? as f64;

    let fourcc = videoio::VideoWriter::fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')?;
    let mut writer = videoio::VideoWriter::new(
        "output.mp4",
        fourcc,
        fps,
        (frame_width, frame_height).into(),
        true,
    )?;

    let mut frame = core::Mat::default();

    while cap.read(&mut frame)? {
        let mut img_buffer = ImageBuffer::new(frame_width as u32, frame_height as u32);
        for y in 0..frame_height {
            for x in 0..frame_width {
                let pixel = frame.at_2d::<core::Vec3b>(y, x)?;
                img_buffer.put_pixel(x as u32, y as u32, Rgb([pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0]]));
            }
        }

        let img = image::DynamicImage::ImageRgb8(img_buffer)
            .resize_exact(640, 640, FilterType::CatmullRom);

        let mut input = Array::zeros((1, 3, 640, 640));
        for pixel in img.pixels() {
            let x = pixel.0 as usize;
            let y = pixel.1 as usize;
            let [r, g, b] = [pixel.2[0], pixel.2[1], pixel.2[2]];
            input[[0, 0, y, x]] = (r as f32) / 255.;
            input[[0, 1, y, x]] = (g as f32) / 255.;
            input[[0, 2, y, x]] = (b as f32) / 255.;
        }

        let outputs: SessionOutputs = model.run(inputs!["images" => input.view()]?)?;
        let output = outputs["output0"].try_extract_tensor::<f32>()?.t().into_owned();

        let mut boxes = Vec::new();
        let output = output.slice(s![.., .., 0]);
        for row in output.axis_iter(Axis(0)) {
            let row: Vec<_> = row.iter().copied().collect();
            let (class_id, prob) = row
                .iter()
                .skip(4)
                .enumerate()
                .map(|(index, value)| (index, *value))
                .reduce(|accum, row| if row.1 > accum.1 { row } else { accum })
                .unwrap();
            
            if prob < 0.5 {
                continue;
            }

            let label = YOLOV8_CLASS_LABELS[class_id];
            let xc = row[0] / 640. * (frame_width as f32);
            let yc = row[1] / 640. * (frame_height as f32);
            let w = row[2] / 640. * (frame_width as f32);
            let h = row[3] / 640. * (frame_height as f32);
            
            boxes.push((
                BoundingBox {
                    x1: xc - w / 2.,
                    y1: yc - h / 2.,
                    x2: xc + w / 2.,
                    y2: yc + h / 2.
                },
                label,
                prob
            ));
        }

        boxes.sort_by(|box1, box2| box2.2.total_cmp(&box1.2));
        let mut result = Vec::new();

        while !boxes.is_empty() {
            result.push(boxes[0]);
            boxes = boxes
                .iter()
                .filter(|box1| intersection(&boxes[0].0, &box1.0) / union(&boxes[0].0, &box1.0) < 0.7)
                .copied()
                .collect();
        }

        for (bbox, label, _confidence) in &result {

            let rect = core::Rect::new(
                bbox.x1 as i32,
                bbox.y1 as i32,
                (bbox.x2 - bbox.x1) as i32,
                (bbox.y2 - bbox.y1) as i32
            );
            
            imgproc::rectangle(
                &mut frame,
                rect,
                core::Scalar::new(0.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0), // Green color
                2,
                imgproc::LINE_8,
                0,
            )?;

            imgproc::put_text(
                &mut frame,
                label,
                core::Point::new(rect.x, rect.y - 5),
                imgproc::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.5,
                core::Scalar::new(0.0, 255.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                1,
                imgproc::LINE_8,
                false,
            )?;
        }

        writer.write(&frame)?;

        highgui::imshow("YOLOv8 Detection", &frame)?;
        if highgui::wait_key(1)? == 27 { // ESC key
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}


you should know that most of those "missing" DLLs are purely from the program probing for their availability. it doesn't require most of them. most of them are mutually exclusive to each other. -- that's a weird pastebin site... how did you pick it?

So how do I fix the error, sir? I just typed "text hosting" on Google :)

SOLVED. Here is what I did : Copy the file opencv_world4xxx.dll to the same directory of your_project.exe. If in cargo run mode, copy to target/debug. Then you will get new error collerated with onnxruntime.dll, then simply download onnxruntime.zip from here : https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime and extract it then copy onnxruntime.dll to the same directory of your_project.exe just like the previous opencv_world file
